# how can I stop my server from freezing when powershell is in 'select' mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, powershell

I didn't believe this until I tested it a few times, but it's really happening.

1. Start rails server and app from powershell: 'rails s'
2. open a web page from that server
3. note how long the page took to get served up
4. now in powershell, select some text
5. reload the webpage from step 2
6. note that the webpage is taking forever to load
7. set up the windows so that you can see the powershell window and web page at the same time
8. go back to powershell and hit 'Enter' (so that the selected text is copied)
9. note that the web page loads as soon as the powershell window leaves select mode

**TLDR**: Rails server started via powershell won't serve pages while powershell is in 'Select' mode.

Is there some setting in powershell that will stop it from doing this? I can see it being helpful when selecting text in the middle of a bat run but when it stops my server it's flipping obnoxious.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with powershell. this is an effect of the windows console subsystem. You'd have the same problem if you ran rails out of a cmd window, or even if you shellexec'd it from a windows app.

Comment: @X0n I was wondering about that, thanks.

Comment: @x0n: Oisin, could you explain what the problem is with the windows console subsystem? Do you know why this is happening? Is this still happening in Win7/2008 with the new conhost.exe?

Comment: hmm, I tried to duplicate this behaviour with a simple script and I could not. Is the rails server watching for keystrokes in its processing loop? This might be the problem...

Comment: I would recommend Console2 and plain `cmd.exe` instead of PowerShell. https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ or via https://chocolatey.org/packages/Console2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a powershell window that you would normally start rails in. Open the properties dialog for the window and *deselect* **QuickEdit Mode** on the Options tab.

Comment: And if they use "control box > edit > mark" instead of the quickedit functionality? you're still hosed.

Comment: Oisin, you're absolutely correct but I think the problem was the accidental clicking on the 'console' window thereby activating the QuickEdit mark/copy action.

Comment: Yeah Greg's right, when I clicked on the window to see what the server was doing I was about 50% of the time activating quickedit without realizing it -- thereby stopping my server from serving pages.

Comment: And now you cannot select any text in the terminal. What if I want both?

Answer (score 0):

I had commented thinking it was just a general issue with the console system, and it probably still is as I cannot see how powershell is involved here as it's just a parent process, but it appears to be isolated to code that is watching for input. I think the rails server might be looking for input during its main loop, and perhaps selecting text in the console is blocking this. Take this simple script that loops - but does not watch for input - on a single thread, writing to a debug listener:

```
ps> $i = 0
ps> while (1) { sleep -seconds 1; [diagnostics.trace]::writeline("ping: $i"); $i++ }
```

Now, run sysinternals/microsoft's free DbgView tool to watch the output. I am using a separate tool instead of writing to the console because this is more like your scenario where web pages are being served in the background to a socket. You can get DbgView from:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

When I select the text in the console, the script does not pause. I even stuffed in a check in the key buffer, and it still did not stop.

I think the Rails server is doing some kind of key checking which is being blocked somehow and interfering with its ability to process requests. It seems retarded, but my script doesn't fail even if I stuff in a check for `[console]::keyavailable`

```
ps> while (1) {
>> sleep -seconds 1;
>> [diagnostics.trace]::writeline("ping: $i");
>> $i++
>> $dummy = [console]::keyavailable
>> }
```

Looks like it's Rail's fault, albeit unintentionally of course.

Comment: Of course the Rails people will probably tell me to get a real OS.

Comment: Yeah. The console subsystem on windows is ass, and always has been.